# Missing Message Id field when mail is sent from SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, email, smtp, pop3

I have a weird situation

If I send mails from Outlook, blackberry etc. `Message Id` field of mail is generated properly but if I send mails from SQL server (using same POP & SMTP server configuration) `Message Id` field of POP message doesn't generate.

What could be reason behind this behavior ? Have read some posts saying that `Message Id` is generated by SMTP server So why the mails only sent from SQL server behaving like this ? Please guide me what should I do ?

I am using SQL server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

when you send mail in even sql, a message id is generated. You would see a comment arising in the output window. mail Id XYZ queued..